# Fetch all contacts with EWS soap request

Tags: web-services, soap, outlook, exchangewebservices

I'm trying to fetch all contacts through Outlook EWS Web Interface.

So far I've managed to query 100 contacts with resolveNames api, but it's not good enough:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:m="
http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:t="http://sc
hemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xml
soap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Header>
    <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2010" />
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <m:ResolveNames ReturnFullContactData="true" SearchScope="ActiveDirectory">
      <m:UnresolvedEntry>wang</m:UnresolvedEntry>
    </m:ResolveNames>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

First, no paging support, I can get only 100 contacts?

And this seems to be a searching function, not a list function.

So any other API to use?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the version of Exchange your using if your using 2010 and its on prem then you would be better to just query Active Directory via LDAP directly. For 2013 and up you can make use of the FindPeople operation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj191039(v=exchg.150).aspx which allows paging if you use the GUID of the address list you want to browse through.